# Get device names of connected clients to the router on Pi

Tags: networking, wireless

Is there any way to get the names of all the devices connected to my WiFi router (Asus RTN13UB1) on my RPi. My Pi will be wireless-ly connected to the same router.

Comment: Welcome to RPi.SE. Related question : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188367/get-devices-name-on-the-network